# Why "No NFC device found" with libnfc and PN532 SHIELD

Tags: arduino, nfc, lib-nfc, adafruit

I installed the libnfc on my ArchLinux and i would use it through my Adafruit PN532 arduino SHIELD.

`nfc-list` returns me the message "No NFC device found".

I have the following file in /etc/nfc/devices.d/pn532.conf that gives me

> nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
>   error   libnfc.driver.pn532_uart    pn53x_check_communication error
>   error   libnfc.chip.pn53x   Unexpected PN53x reply!
>   nfc-list: ERROR: Unable to open NFC device: pn532_uart:/dev/ttyACM0

Any idea about how to fix that ?
TY

Comment: Are you sure you have the cable RX/TX properly setup? Are you able to use the NFC shield with an arduino?

Comment: I am able to use the shield with the arduino. My problem is referring to the lib imo

Answer (score 5):

First of all verify your Rx/Tx connections.

And then Configure LIBNFC with following command :

`1) ./configure --with-drivers=pn532_uart --sysconfdir=/etc --prefix=/usr --enable-serial-autoprobe`

`2) make clean all`

`3) sudo make install all`

And Finally 
`4) LIBNFC_LOG_LEVEL=3`

Now Try `5) nfc-list`

[If Still problem persists try this tutorial from nfc-tool](http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=Libnfc:Arduino)

> [Source/Reference](http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=Libnfc:configuration)

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked to swap the RX <-> TX

Comment: This answer might solve the problem but does nothing to address the issue and indicates that something was most likely not set up correctly.

Comment: yes, wrong setup using OrangePi and https://dangerousthings.com/wp-content/uploads/PN532_Manual_V3-1.pdf

Comment: Edit your answer and maybe provide the solution you found in that manual?

Comment: That manual helped me identify the RX TX pins, but after 2 days of any configuration not working, even with having set in the OrangePi's armbian uart3 in the config to the according pins. Still, i had to swap the two pins...
Oh!... so RX goes to TX, not the way i was used to a -> a and b->b, but output->input